# Set breakpoint for Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the bootstrap grid system (3.4.1) in my react.js project. I have two columns C1 and C2.

### |  C1  |  C2 |

If I shrink the width of the screen C2 breaks under C1 by default.
But I want the opposite C1 should break under C2.
Is it possible to achive this while only using bootstrap?

Comment: Add minimal working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3 you can do as below,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 bg-info">C2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4 bg-success">C1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working codepen for the same https://codepen.io/R1112/pen/RwbzmEL

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Bootstrap 3.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="float:right">
      C2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="float:right">
      C1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The Problem is C1 Need to be on the left and C2 on the Right. Only when the screen width gets smaller C1 should break under C2

Comment: It will be with this code. BS 3 is using float left by default. By using float right, C1 will be on the left and C2 on the right. On small screens both will be stacked with C2 on top of C1.